# Open multiple files with an application using QDesktopServices

Tags: qt

Currently a user can select a song on my Qt application and play it using his default media player. I have implemented  this using QDesktopServices::openUrl().

However I want the user to be able to select multiple songs and enque them in his media player. With the current implementation as soon as the user selects the second song the first song stops and the second one starts to play.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid, enqueueing songs cannot be done, using `QDesktopServices::openUrl()` only. I see two main ways to do that:

1. You can adjust your player to enqueue all songs, opened with `QDesktopServices::openUrl()` (which is practically equivalent to double clicking in your file magager).
2. Most players I know have parameters, which tell them to enqueue listed file(s). For example, `deadbeef` can be launched with parameter `--queue`. You can use `QProcess::startDetached` to launch the player with parameters.

In both ways you need to know the exact player, you are using.

Comment: "In both ways you need to know the exact player, you are using." - I had considered that approach too but I could not find a cross platform way of determining a default application for a file type. Without that I won't know which application to invoke. Also asking the user to adjust his player settings is probably not the right way to go. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!!!!

Comment: You could add support for several most popular players and let the user choose between them. You'll need to determine whether the player is installed in the system though.

Comment: My application should run on linux, mac and windows. The number of players that I would have to support would be large and coupled with the trouble I have to go through to find out if they are installed and the handling if they are not would mean a lot of work. Most media players automatically queue songs if multiple songs are passed to them as arguments. So I was thinking if I could pass a list of urls to QDesktopServices::openUrl it would have been great...

Answer (score 0):

If your player supports MPRIS (if it's a media player which is expected to be integrated to a modern Unix desktop, it does), the [addTrack](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/Track_List_Interface.html) method of the D-BUS MPRIS interface for track list manipulation should help you. You might want to call `QDesktopServices::openUrl` on the first file to make sure that a player is running before you invoke that.